# how to reference the Java Script in Android Application?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jqmath

I've downloaded jqMath files to show mathematical formula in my app. I copied and pasted all the downloaded files; I mean the js,the css and html in the asset folder of the android project in Eclipse. Then, I wrote in my java document (ventana is a WebView instance)

```
     ventana.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myhtml.html");
```

and tested, but it's seen as it doesn't find the referenced files in the html document, which are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=UnifrakturMaguntia">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../mathscribe/jqmath-0.4.0.css">

<script src="../mathscribe/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../mathscribe/jqmath-etc-0.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

Somebody in stackoverflow suggested to add

```
    </link>
```

for the link tags, I did that but didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried dropping the `../`? Have you enabled javaScript through `setJavaScriptEnabled( true )`?

Comment: sorry, I dropped `../mathscribe/` plus your suggestion and now works fine ! , now I trying to figure out how to change the size of the fonts. Thanks 323go

Comment: For font-sizes, you might want to look into the zoom-level and viewport settings. `WebView` is a funny creature, but quite configurable.